# How does reference counting work?

Tags: c, memory, pointers, memory-management, reference

How do reference counted structures work? For example let's look at `SDL_Surface`:

```
typedef struct SDL_Surface
{
    ...
    int refcount;
} SDL_Surface;

s = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(...); // <-- what happens here?
SDL_FreeSurface(s); // <-- and here?
```

How do I implement reference counting in my own code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SDL_CreateRGBSurface` will allocate a new instance of `SDL_Surface` (or a suitable derived structure), and increment the reference count (setting it to 1).

`SDL_FreeSurface` will decrement the reference count, and check if it's zero. If it is, that means that no other objects are using the surface, and it will be deallocated.

SDL also guarantees that the refcount is incremented whenever the object gets used somewhere else (e.g. in the renderer). So, if the reference count is nonzero when `SDL_FreeSurface` is called, then some other object must be using it. That other object will eventually also call `SDL_FreeSurface` and release the surface for good.

Reference counting allows you to cheaply track objects without the overhead of a cycle-collecting garbage collector. However, one drawback is that it won't handle cycles (e.g. where object A holds a reference to B, which in turn holds a reference to B); in those cases, the cycles will keep the objects involved alive even when all other external references are gone.

To implement refcounting, you simply need to add a refcount field to any objects you want to refcount, and ensure (in your public API, and internally) that every allocation and deallocation of the object goes through the appropriate refcount-maintaining interface (which you must define). Finally, when an object or function wants a reference to your refcounted objects, they must first get the reference by incrementing the refcount (directly or through some interface). When they are done they must decrement the refcount.

Comment: Nice explanation +1. In the first line, 'setting it to 1' applies only if reference count was 0.

Comment: I assume that `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` allocates the object anew, so that it will start with a refcount of 1, which is how _most_ refcount implementations work.